# The virtual printer I used to print javafx node using printerjob prints something jiberish. What's the reason for this error?

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, printing

I have already tried two different virtual printer, and the result is same:

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGL2j.png) is saved as PDF whereas it was supposed to print/save [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQgGg.png).

Is there an error in the code (below), or could this be a bug in `javafx.printerjob`? The OS is MacOS High Sierra 10x, in case that matters.

The code is:

```
private void print(Node node, Stage owner) {
    System.out.println("Creating a printer job...");
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null) {
        boolean success = job.printPage(node);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: looks like character encoding problems. May have something to do with your local.